# How to combine multiple selectors for the same rule

Tags: css

I can't combine these selectors into a single CSS rule. I'm trying to edit the width of certain form fields.

```
input#input_9_2 {
  max-width: 500px;
}

input#input_9_3 {
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

When I try to combine them, the rule does not apply to either. But they work when written separately, as above.

Comment: how you try to combine them

Comment: if one of the stated solutions solve your problem then make sure you accept that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group CSS selectors in a style sheet, you [use commas to separate multiple grouped selectors](https://www.lifewire.com/comma-in-css-selectors-3467052) in the style. In this example, the style affects two classes `input#input_9_2` and `input#input_9_3`.

```
input#input_9_2,
input#input_9_3
{
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

The comma means "**and**", so this selector applies to all `input#input_9_2` elements and `input#input_9_3` elements. If the comma were missing, the selector would instead apply to all `input#input_9_3` elements that are a child of an `input#input_9_2`. That is a different kind of selector, so the comma is important.

Any form of the selector can be grouped with any other selector.

Answer (score -1):

use a [selector list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors)

```css
input#input_9_2, input#input_9_3 {
  max-width: 500px;
}
```